# How to type a dynamically sized array in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to type an array where the first element is always a number, and the rest of the elements are always strings, and the length as to be at least 1.

Here is my best effort:

```js
type MyArray =
  | [number]
  | [number, string]
  | [number, string, string]
  | [number, string, string, string];
```

How do I make that go on forever?

Comment: I don't think you can type it the way you've described. You could do what you currently with as many unions as you actually need, or you could use a type like `(number | string)[]` and helper functions to extract the `number` from the first item and `string`s from the rest, or what I would do is use an object type that has `{ foo: number, bar: string[] }`

Comment: `[number, ...string[]]` will work in recent versions of TypeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before TypeScript 3.0 there really wasn't anything better than a union like you have.  But then a bunch of related new features were introduced to better support tuple types, and specifically their relationship to lists of function parameters.  And since functions support a final [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) representing the type of an indefinite number of parameters as an array, it made sense to introduce a final [rest element in a tuple](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#rest-elements-in-tuple-types) representing the type of an indefinite number of tuple elements as an array.

Hey, in fact, your use case is explicitly mentioned as an example in the documentation:

> For example, `[number, ...string[]]` means tuples with a `number` element followed by any number of `string` elements.

So let's try that:

```
type MyArray = [number, ...string[]];
const okay0: MyArray = [0]; // okay
const okay1: MyArray = [1, "a"]; // okay
const okay2: MyArray = [2, "a", "b"]; // okay
const okay3: MyArray = [3, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]; // okay

const bad0: MyArray = [0, "a", false]; // error!
//    ~~~~ <-- boolean is not assignable to string
const bad1: MyArray = ["x", "y"]; // error!
//                     ~~~ <-- string is not assignable to number
const bad2: MyArray = []; // error!
//    ~~~~ <--- property '0' is missing (i.e., bad2[0] is missing)
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCAnRBDEUC8UDaA7ArgLYBGEiANFAHQ0DOwiAlrgObYC67A3AFADGAe1z0oAgNZoADAC5YCZGkw5J3KAHo1oiSH5CR4tAEZZcJKnRZshygCIUN1Rq1pdw4M5AAmE-PNLsnrb2tsQOXOqaBjqCbh4AzD5mipZxQTYh6VA2fJk2ACa5ELkAZrksuQAWuYy5AFZhER48riLEKHkyckkWymmUxSgANrQQjppkiAKIAIQ8TlALAH7Li1AAPAC0G1DEAgKDECi4UIy0ULgC7ii0tIwsuCjEB1DAAlD0TKwt7m15xl0KHrYGwAD1yIAaTgmU1m8wW8IRiMRK3WW3eDGYLBOZwuVxudweT2gr3ORFIiG+O3a3gBfksYyg0Jmc008JWq02aLAk0giFAUAA5JIBdioIRTrdWFAABSMKgQKiUX6ebAqUXi-GsACUPCAA)