# TypeScript: How to type an array of number or null elements where the first element cannot be null?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to create a valid type for an array of number where any element can be null except the first one.

My best try so far cannot handle array of any size:

```
type NulNum = number | null
type MyArray = 
    | [number, NulNum]
    | [number, NulNum, NulNum]
    | [number, NulNum, NulNum, NulNum]
    | [number, NulNum, NulNum, NulNum, NulNum]
    // ...


// valid cases, should compile properly
let a: MyArray = [1, null]
a = [1, 1]
a = [1, 1, null]
a = [1, 1, null, null]

// invalid cases, should trigger a compilation error
a = [null, 1]
a = [null, null]
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found the answer based on suggested linked stackoverflow questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56814700/2523414

```
type MyArray = [number, ...(number | null)[]]


// valid cases, should compile properly
let a: MyArray = [1, null]
a = [1, 1]
a = [1, 1, null]
a = [1, 1, null, null]

// invalid cases, should trigger a compilation error
a = [null, 1]
a = [null, null]
```